# Does Apache NetBeans 9.0 support java 11?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-11, netbeans-9

Can anyone say if Apache NetBeans 9.0 support java 11 and if so what are the requirements to make that work?

Prensently I can compile and run java 11 code in NetBeans 9.9 but it is underlined with red and the error message is "cannot find symbol ...".

Below is the pom.xml file I use:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>IoTlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ioTlite</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>ioTlite</name>
        <description>ioTlite backend project with Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RC1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>10</source>
                        <target>10</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

How, for example pom-file should be changed?

Comment: I think you need NetBeans 10 for that. The current "vote candidate" (pretty much the same as a "release candidate") can be downloaded here: https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-10.0-vc4/

Comment: Did you install the "nbjavac" plugin in NetBeans 9?

Comment: I installed NetBeans 10, and yes, indeed, the issue is gone now - so the issue solved, thank you!

Comment: The Netbeans 9.0 web site states [Java 9 and 10 Support](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/), so support for Java 11 is conspicuous in its absence. NetBeans 9.0 was released prior to the release of Java 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No NetBeans 9 doesn’t support Java 11 (only 9 and 10) [[1](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/)].

NetBeans 10 which was planned to be released in November [[2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+Release+Roadmap)] will support Java 11 [[3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+10.0+New+and+Noteworthy)]. Unfortunately, it’s not available yet (at least as official release).

The latest release candidate can be downloaded here

https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/

As NetBeans 10 latest vote candidate 5 is in the final release vote stage [[4]](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-general/201812.mbox/%3Cb6a74e2e-2c5d-7ec1-bd8b-890cf4901a53@gmail.com%3E) we should expect a final release within the next days.

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans 10 [has been released](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/index.html) with JDK 11 support:

> ### JDK 11 Support
>
> JDK 11 support has been enhanced in the following ways:
>
> - Integration with the nb-javac project, adding support for JDK 11.
> - Removed the CORBA modules.
> - Support for JEP 309, Dynamic Class-File Constants.
> - Support for JEP 323, Local-Variable Syntax for Lambda Parameters.
> - Support for LVTI Support for Lamdba Parameters
> - New Hint to convert variable type to 'var' for lambda parameters(JDK
>     11 and above)
> - Code completion for var lambda parameters
> - Code completion support for var type lambda parameters.(JDK 11 and
>     above)
>
> See the [JDK 11 Confluence Page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Feature%3A+JDK+11) for more detailed features.

Donwload page: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html