# Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 Build Fails on Java Applications

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-18.04, netbeans-9

I am getting the following **Build Failed** message for each and every Java Application I try to run.

I am running **Apache Netbeans IDE 9.0** with **OpenJDK 11**, on **Ubuntu 18.04** (with sudo)

```
ant -f "/media/rocketruwan/My Data/Work/Software Developemt/NetBeans Projects/JavaApplicationx" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Djavac.includes=javaapplicationx/NewJFrame.java -Drun.class=javaapplicationx.NewJFrame run-single
init:
Deleting: /media/rocketruwan/My Data/Work/Software Developemt/NetBeans Projects/JavaApplicationx/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /media/rocketruwan/My Data/Work/Software Developemt/NetBeans Projects/JavaApplicationx/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /media/rocketruwan/My Data/Work/Software Developemt/NetBeans Projects/JavaApplicationx/build/classes
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Update:
Upon further browsing, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594558/does-apache-netbeans-9-0-support-java-11) which revealed that **Apache Netbeans 9.0 does not support Java 11**. Moving to [NetBeans 10.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html) which supports Java 11 **solved only one part of the problem**, which is running the Java Application from within the IDE. But trying to build it still gives the same error message.

Comment: This is not much to work on as there is no real error message. In my opinion you should rather create a Maven project anyway as other IDEs can open them.