# Netbeans can't find JDK and JRE

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, java-6

I'm trying to install netbeans and it cannot locate the JDK folder. Things I've tried so far:-

I tried specifying the path in the installer as`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1` as well as `C:\Program Files\Java` . I get an error saying JDK is not in the 
folder.

I tried installing from command prompt with `netbeans-8.0.2-windows.exe --javahome "C:\\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1"`. This removes the JDK error but I now get JRE not found error.

So I tried this `netbeans-8.0.2-windows.exe --javahome "C:\\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201"`. Now I get JDK not found error.

My PATH variable is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1` and the JAVA_HOME variable is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1 ; C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Download a jdk for Java 8. Netbeans 8 doesn't support Java 11, and a Java 8 JRE is not a JDK.

Comment: See: [Does Apache NetBeans 9.0 support java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53594558/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans installer issue with jdk 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53690482/2985643).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans 8 does not run with JDK 11.

More info https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/

> JDK 8 is required for installing and running the Java SE, Java EE and
>   All NetBeans Bundles. NetBeans 8.2 does not run on JDK 9 or later